Joining two CTEs along with other tables but only showing results for one CTE
Industry: Insurance
We have a stored procedure that is intended to filter out and identify AgentLevel and LeadPayorID for an insurance carrier. We have two CTE's "MaxELPDate" and "MaxPFLDate" to identify when an agent is ELP or PFL based on the date of the change to this status. What's happening is that it is only returning EITHER ELP agents OR PFL agents, and even this it's leaving out some agents when it returns ELP data. The initial code is as follows:
    WITH MaxElpDate AS
    (
        SELECT LeadRecipientId, LeadPayorId, MAX(UpdatedDate) AS UpdatedDate
        FROM LeadBilling
        WHERE LeadRecipientId != LeadPayorId
        GROUP BY LeadRecipientId, LeadPayorId
    ),
    MaxPflDate AS 
    (
        SELECT LeadRecipientId, LeadPayorId, MAX(UpdatedDate) AS UpdatedDate
        FROM LeadBilling
        WHERE LeadRecipientId = LeadPayorId
        GROUP BY LeadRecipientId, LeadPayorId
    )
    SELECT 
        a.AgentId, 
        a.FirstName + ' ' + a.LastName AS Agent, 
        mo.AdvanceAmount as MOOReclaim,
        mo.CommissionAmount AS MOOCommission, mo.CarrierID, mo.CommissionPct,
        CAST(mo.IssueDate AS DATE) AS EffectiveDate,
        CAST(mo.StatementDate AS DATE) AS StatementDate,
        CASE 
            WHEN med.UpdatedDate IS NULL THEN mpd.LeadPayorId
            WHEN mpd.UpdatedDate IS NULL THEN med.LeadPayorId
            WHEN DATEDIFF(day, med.UpdatedDate, mpd.UpdatedDate) >= 0 
                AND mo.StatementDate >= mpd.UpdatedDate THEN mpd.LeadPayorId
            WHEN DATEDIFF(day, med.UpdatedDate, mpd.UpdatedDate) < 0 
                AND mo.StatementDate BETWEEN mpd.UpdatedDate AND med.UpdatedDate THEN mpd.LeadPayorId
            ELSE mpd.LeadPayorId
        END AS LeadPayorId,
        CASE
            WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, mo.IssueDate, mo.StatementDate) >= 12 THEN 2 -- in DateDiff when first date is older (smaller) the result is positive
            ELSE 1
        END AS CommissionType, -- 1 is first year 2 is renewal
        CASE
            -- in DateDiff when first date is older (smaller) the result is positive
            --WHEN med.UpdatedDate IS NULL THEN 2
            WHEN mpd.UpdatedDate IS NULL THEN 1
            WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, mo.IssueDate, mpd.UpdatedDate) > 0 THEN 1
            WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, mo.StatementDate, mpd.UpdatedDate) > 0
                AND DATEDIFF(DAY, mo.IssueDate, mpd.UpdatedDate) < 0 THEN 1
            WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, mo.IssueDate, med.UpdatedDate) < 0
                AND DATEDIFF(DAY, med.UpdatedDate, mpd.UpdatedDate) < 0 THEN 1
            ELSE 2
        END AS AgentLevel, -- 1 is ELP 2 is PFL
         med.UpdatedDate as elpupdateddate,
         mpd.UpdatedDate as pflupdateddate,
         mo.PolicyNumber,
         DATEDIFF(MONTH, mo.IssueDate, mo.StatementDate) as EffvsStateDiff
    FROM Agents a
    JOIN AgentWritingNumbers awn ON awn.AgentId = a.AgentId
    JOIN MOOCommissionStatements mo ON mo.WritingAgentNumber = awn.WritingNumber 
        AND mo.StatementDate >= '2023-01-01'
    JOIN LeadBilling lb ON lb.LeadRecipientId = a.AgentId
    JOIN MaxElpDate med ON lb.LeadRecipientId = med.LeadRecipientId
    LEFT JOIN MaxPflDate mpd ON lb.LeadRecipientId = mpd.LeadRecipientId
    GROUP BY a.AgentId, a.FirstName, a.LastName, mo.StatementDate, mo.IssueDate,
    med.UpdatedDate,
    mpd.UpdatedDate,
        med.LeadPayorId,
        mpd.LeadPayorId,
        mo.AdvanceAmount, mo.CommissionAmount, mo.PolicyNumber,mo.CarrierID,mo.CommissionPct
    ORDER BY a.FirstName, a.LastName, mo.StatementDate, mo.IssueDate

END

And returns the following results:



AgentId
StatementDate
LeadPayorId
CommissionType
AgentLevel
elpupdateddate
pflupdateddate
EffvsStateDiff




482
8/6/2024
368
1
1
8/16/2022
NULL
-1


482
8/13/2024
368
1
1
8/16/2022
NULL
0


482
8/13/2024
368
1
1
8/16/2022
NULL
0


482
8/13/2024
368
1
1
8/16/2022
NULL
-1


482
8/13/2024
368
1
1
8/16/2022
NULL
-1


482
8/13/2024
368
1
1
8/16/2022
NULL
-1


482
8/20/2024
368
1
1
8/16/2022
NULL
0


482
8/20/2024
368
1
1
8/16/2022
NULL
0


482
9/10/2024
368
1
1
8/16/2022
NULL
0



There should also be results showing with an AgentID of 724 and LeadPayorID of 150 for this query.
Then we commented out the JOIN and GROUP BY for med.(ELP) and got this:



AgentId
StatementDate
LeadPayorId
CommissionType
AgentLevel
pflupdateddate
EffvsStateDiff




20
8/27/2024
20
1
2
7/24/2018
0


20
9/3/2024
20
1
2
7/24/2018
1


20
9/3/2024
20
1
2
7/24/2018
1


482
8/13/2024
NULL
1
1
NULL
-1


482
8/13/2024
NULL
1
1
NULL
-1


113
8/13/2024
113
1
2
2/8/2019
-1


113
8/20/2024
113
1
2
2/8/2019
0


123
8/20/2024
123
1
2
9/16/2020
0


123
9/10/2024
123
1
2
9/16/2020
0



So PFL agents show up (matching AgentID and LeadPayorID) but also the ELP AgentID of 482 shows up, but without the LeadPayorID filled (I'm assuming because we removed the code to find the LeadPayorID of ELP agents for this query)
When we then keep the ELP JOIN and GROUPBY and comment out the PFL (mpd) JOIN and GROUP BY and any other reference to mpd, we get the first table I shared.
How can I have all the necessary information populate, and also not leave out data like in the case of the AgentID 724 and LeadPayorID 150 combination?
I tried to be extra thorough based on feedback from my previous question that was in a similar vein to this. If more information is needed please let me know.

You have JOIN MaxElpDate (an inner join) but  LEFT JOIN MaxPflDate. Therefore, this assumes that every LeadBilling.LeadRecipientId of interest must have a MaxElpDate e.g., a record where LeadRecipientId != LeadPayorId. Is that true for the records that don't show up? (Note also that if LeadPayorId is NULL, then LeadRecipientId != LeadPayorId will not be true).

Not sure why this needs two CTEs anyway, why not just conditional aggregation in one query MAX(CASE WHEN LeadRecipientId = LeadPayorId THEN UpdatedDate END) AS MaxPfl, MAX(CASE WHEN LeadRecipientId <> LeadPayorId THEN UpdatedDate END) AS MaxElp also do this as window functions OVER (PARTITION BY LeadRecipientId) then you don't need to join the table again.

@seanb there is a combo where leadrecipientID ! = LeadPayorID and it's left out. That record would have a MaxELP date but it's not showing up

@Charlieface thank you. I tried this and I still got the same result as shown in my second example, where it's leaving out the LeadRecipient of 724 and LeadPayorID of 150. I'm not sure if the Partition would fix that, but I wasn't sure where to put it in the query so I left it out.

OK lets' have some sample data for all relevant tables and expected results because it's not clear what you want at this stage.

try a cut-down query using left joins to inspect the data: e.g.`SELECT
a.AgentId,
med.LeadRecipientId med_ldrid,
mpd.LeadRecipientId mpd_ldrid,
med.ELP_UpdatedDate,
mpd.PFL_UpdatedDate
FROM Agents a
JOIN MOOCommissionStatements mo ON mo.WritingAgentNumber = awn.WritingNumber AND mo.StatementDate >= '2023-01-01'
LEFT JOIN LeadBilling lb ON lb.LeadRecipientId = a.AgentId
LEFT JOIN MaxElpDate med ON lb.LeadRecipientId = med.LeadRecipientId
LEFT JOIN MaxPflDate mpd ON lb.LeadRecipientId = mpd.LeadRecipientId
order by med.LeadRecipientId, mpd.LeadRecipientId`

@Charlieface So turns out that the way this carrier reports the data doesn't allow for what I'm looking for to even exist as sample data. We initially thought it was an error in the code, but it's actually the data itself. Sorry for the inconvenience here
